# EXC_BAD_ACCESS depending on string length in Core Data

Tags: core-data, nsstring, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

This is the strangest / most annoying bug I've ever encountered! I have a modal tableview with an NSMutableArray selectedObjects. With selectedObjects, I compare NSStrings from the datasource with containsObject to see if a row needs to be highlighted.

Ok, here is the strange part! My selectedObjects is derived from a string in my Core Data sqlite database. When each of the NSStrings in selectedObjects is =< 4 characters, I don't get an exc_bad_access. However, if one of the selectedObjects has a string > 4 characters, once the modal tableview shows, I get an exc_bad_access!

Something else that is strange is that when I assign the selectedObjects array manually (i.e., [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"selected 1", @"selected 2", nil]; ), I don't get the exc_bad_access. I can even do [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"selected 1"];.

It seems to all depend on the selectedObject string in my Core Data object graph. For example, if I set a default for my selected string in my xcdatamodel that is 4 characters, I don't get the exc_bad_access (e.g., @"asdf"), but if I set it as @"asdfg", then it causes the error. I'm really confused as to why it make a difference!

Has anyone ever encountered / heard of a similar bug?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The saga continues! This is also very odd. If I include a space in my selectedObject string that is stored in the sqlite database, there's no exc_bad_access. For example, if I do @"asdfg", it crashes, but if I do @"asdf g", there's no crash. I'm using the SQL Manager Firefox plug-in to edit my sql entries.

Comment: Update 2: So it has something to do with my UITextView (which is in a UITableView and pops up the modal view when selected through shouldTextViewBeginEditing). For some reason, my UITextView gets released after the second call of shouldTextViewBeginEditing if I don't manipulate the text in some way. For example, it will crash if I simply return NO; on the first line of shouldTextViewBeginEditing. But if I do textView.text = textView.text before returning, there's no exc_bad_access.

Comment: It seems quite possible that the bug is elsewhere in your code. Are you using ARC or retain–release?